# The "improvement" filter disallows removal of inappropriate tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, edits

The edit filter that tries to ensure an edit is worthwhile, or something, disallows the removal of (for example) a programming language tag on a question that has absolutely nothing to do with the language referenced by the tag. I don't see how that's a feature.

[Here is the question that led me to post this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683659/base-256-to-base-10) It's the quite common problem of people asking Java questions and tagging the question with JavaScript too. (The question has/had a suggested edit, but when I initially attempted to change it it didn't.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the bug is, sorry. Didn't the edit you approved (http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2181400) already do that?

Comment: I attempted to edit the question and just delete the JavaScript tag. The site wouldn't let me.

Comment: I cannot duplicate this issue now; was there some transient feature active a while ago?

Answer (score 1):

Questions with pending suggested edits can't be re-tagged, that's by design.

Comment: It didn't have a pending suggested edit when I initially tried to remove the incorrect tag. Your edit adding the "status-bydesign" tag is therefore inappropriate.

Comment: ... and even if there were a pending suggested edit, the error message I got didn't mention that at all. It just stated that the change I made didn't improve the question enough.

Comment: do you remember if you've done it via the inline tag editor or the full post editor?

Comment: I used the full post editor.